# tomcat6 start failed, but the service status is running

Tags: tomcat

I've installed tomcat6 on my CentOS. It does not work.

```
# service tomcat6 start
Starting tomcat6:                                         [FAILED] 
# service tomcat6 stop
Stopping tomcat6:                                         [  OK  ]
# service tomcat6 status
tomcat6 (pid ) is running...
```

the tomcat6 has no pid, anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Please do `rm /var/run/tomcat6.pid`, start tomcat service again and give report.

Comment: i removed but start fail, the log cat /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out -> This account is currently not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the account probably has the incorrect shell set. I have never seen this happen to tomcat, though ...

do the following to confirm this is the problem:

```
$ grep tomcat /etc/passwd
```

It should say something like the following:

```
tomcat:x:<nnn>:<nnn>::/home/tomcat:/bin/sh
```

where <nnn> are numbers. You will likely have something like this:

```
tomcat:x:<nnn>:<nnn>::/home/tomcat:/bin/false
```

or

```
tomcat:x:<nnn>:<nnn>::/home/tomcat:/sbin/nologin
```

Sometimes, the tomcat username also has a version number suffix, such as tomcat6 or tomcat7, please replace "tomcat" in the command below with the name of your tomcat user.

Use the chsh command:

```
$ chsh -s /bin/sh tomcat
```

The restart tomcat:

```
$ service restart tomcat6
```

Please check catalina.out for errors.

Comment: Why do you suspect that?

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# grep tomcat /etc/passwd
tomcat:x:91:91:Apache Tomcat:/usr/share/tomcat6:/sbin/nologin

see

Comment: i used chsh -s /bin/sh tomcat, but not work, i typed service tomcat6 status, nothing output

Comment: @Mikel: "This account is currently not available." as reported by op in a comment. You usually get this error when you attempt to use an account which has an invalid shell set.

Comment: @hkinterview : "i used chsh -s /bin/sh tomcat, but not work ..." what does this mean ? You typed that command, did you get an error? If you typed that command and got no error, run "service tomcat6 restart" then  "service tomcat6 status". Please report your findings

Comment: that means i still can't make the tomcat6 start after used that command. There is no error. service tomcat6 start [ok] service tomcat6 status [nothong], there is a tomcat6.pid in /var/run/tomcat6.pid , i have to remove that by rm.